# Form displays differently in IE and Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

In IE, this code displays the form inside the top div, where it should:

```
<div style = 'height:100px;background-color:#FF6600'>
<form name = "search" action = "search_result.php" method = "get" style = "text-align:right;">
<input type = "text" name = "query" id = "query" maxlength = "100">
<br />
<input type = "radio" value = "Search users" name = "user" id = "user">&nbsp;<input type = "radio" value = "Search topics" name = "topics" id = "topics">
<input type = "Submit" value = "Go">
</form>
</div>
```

But in Chrome, it displays the form below the div. Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I omitted some PHP code which `echos` some of the HTML. Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','phpuser','mypss');
$db = mysql_select_db('phpuser');
echo "<div style = 'float:none;clear:both;height:100px;background-color:#FF6600'>";
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])&&$_SESSION['user']!="")
{
echo "<a href = 'userinfo.php'>".$_SESSION['user']."</a>";
echo "&nbsp;";
echo "|&nbsp;";
echo "<a href = 'logout.php'>Log out</a>&nbsp;";
echo "|&nbsp;";
}
echo "<a href = 'home.php'>Home</a>";
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])||$_SESSION['user']=="")
{
echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
echo "<a href = 'login.php'>Log in</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
echo "<a href = 'signup.php'>Sign up</a>&nbsp;";
}

function trimtext($text)
{
$newtext = substr($text,0,15);
$newtext .= "...";
return $newtext;
}
?>
<h1 style = "color:black">My blog</h1>
<form name = "search" action = "search_result.php" method = "get" style = "text-align:right;">
<input type = "text" name = "query" id = "query" maxlength = "100">
<br />
<input type = "radio" value = "Search users" name = "user" id = "user">&nbsp;<input type = "radio" value = "Search topics" name = "topics" id = "topics">
<input type = "Submit" value = "Go">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aren't forms block level elements? Does your form really need to be in a div?

Comment: Seems to display fine for me, http://jsfiddle.net/a3njc/

Comment: Not really related but it's a good practice to add id to your form, and if you need more space between inputs use css properties instead of <br/>

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, your markup is wrong." Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work but this works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @Rob It displays as I want it to in IE, but not as I want it to in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to fix Chrome. Chrome will show what you wrote while IE will make stuff up as it goes along. It's like doing math on two calculators where one is broken and the broken one is showing the answer you want and you try and get the working calculator to show the same answer.

Comment: @Rob is this why everyone hates IE?

Comment: Yes but that is only reason number 9164.

Comment: @Rob upvoted for making me laugh :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any float property applied to elements nearer to that form? if that is that case, try adding     `<div style="float: none; clear: both;"></div>`

or

just remove the form's parent div and apply div's styles to form itself.

Comment: There is a title. I omitted some of the code as a lot of it is echoed from PHP. I will edit my question now.